# Why does my Vue JS app crashes in prod server but works fine in dev?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, web-frontend, dev-to-production

I have run my Vue JS app in development server multiple times and never faced a single issue with any of the functions. However, as soon as I deploy my application in the production server everything except this specific discount function causes my system to crash.

So after selecting one of the option (either amount or percentage) and as soon as I type in the value inside the input box, my application stops working.

I am still very new to web app development so it would be great if someone can help me out with this. TIA

[image: Discount form]

This is my function that I am using to calculate discounts:

```
applyDiscount(){
           this.balance=this.totalCost-this.totalPaid
        
            if(this.isPercentage=='Percentage'){               
                if(this.discountAmount<=100 ){                    
                this.discount=(this.totalCost/100)*this.discountAmount
                this.form.discount=this.discount
                this.str=""          

                    if(this.discount<=this.totalCost-this.totalPaid){
                        this.adjustment=this.totalCost-this.discount
                        this.balance=this.balance-this.discount
                        this.str=""
                    }
                    else{
                        this.str="Discount amount exceeding balance"                     
                    }                  
                }
                else{
                    this.str="Percentage is exceeding 100%"                     
                }  

            }else if(this.isPercentage=='Amount'){
                this.str=""
                this.discount=this.discountAmount
                this.form.discount=this.discount

                if(this.discount<=this.totalCost-this.totalPaid){
                    this.adjustment=this.totalCost-this.discount
                    this.balance=this.balance-this.discount
                    this.str=""

                    }
                    else{
                        this.str="Discount amount exceeding balance"                        
                    } 
            }
        },
```

This template code:

```
 <!--discount-->

                <form @submit.prevent>
                    <div class="tracking-widest text-lg text-left title-font font-bold text-gray-500  border-b border-gray-300 ">
                    Discount: 
                    </div>
                     <!--discount-->
                <div class="inline-flex items-center mt-3 ">

                <label for="" class="mb-3 text-gray-800">Give discount in?</label>

                <input type="radio" name="test_id" @change="onChange($event)" value="Amount" class="form-radio h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600 mr-2" ><span class="ml-2 mr-2 text-gray-700">Amount</span>
                <input type="radio" name="test_id" @change="onChange($event)" value="Percentage" class="form-radio h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600 mr-1"><span class="ml-2 mr-2 text-gray-700">Percentage</span>
                
                </div>
            
                <div class="flex justify-start">
                    <div class="">
                        <label class="text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" for="discount">Discount Amount</label>
                        <input  @keypress="isNumber($event)" v-model.number="discountAmount" id="discount" type="text"
                            class="block w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-gray-700 bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring">
                    </div>                        
                </div>
                <div>{{this.applyDiscount()}}</div>

                <!--discount-->


        <div v-if="this.str.length>=1">


                        <div class=" flex items-center mt-10 px-8">
                            <svg class="h-6 w-6 fill-current text-red-400 mr-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path
                                    d="M2.93 17.07A10 10 0 1 1 17.07 2.93 10 10 0 0 1 2.93 17.07zm12.73-1.41A8 8 0 1 0 4.34 4.34a8 8 0 0 0 11.32 11.32zM9 11V9h2v6H9v-4zm0-6h2v2H9V5z" />
                                </svg>
                            <div>
                                <p class="font-medium text-red-500">{{str}}</p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
               


              


            <!--after discount-->

            <div class="flex justify-end items-end ml-6"  >
                    <div class=" mt-5  w-full sm:w-2/4 lg:w-1/4">
                        <div class=" justify-between mb-3">
                            <div class="text-gray-400 text-md flex font-bold uppercase  "><span
                                    class="ml-5 mt-2">Total Cost:</span> <span
                                    class="text-lg rounded ml-2 text-gray-500 "><span class="text-xl" >&#2547;{{this.totalCost}}</span></span> </div>
                            <div class=" w-40">
                                <div class="text-gray-800 font-medium" x-html="netTotal"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" justify-between mb-3">
                            <div class="text-gray-400 text-md flex font-bold uppercase "><span
                                    class="ml-5 mt-2">Total Paid:</span> <span
                                    class="text-lg rounded ml-2 text-gray-500 "><span class="text-xl" >&#2547;{{this.totalPaid}}</span></span> </div>
                            <div class=" w-40">
                                <div class="text-gray-800 font-medium" x-html="netTotal"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" justify-between mb-3">
                            <div class="text-gray-400 text-md  flex font-bold uppercase "><span
                                    class="ml-5 mt-2">Discount:</span> <span
                                    class="text-lg  ml-2 text-gray-600"><span class="text-xl" >&#2547;{{this.discount}}</span></span> </div>
                            <div class=" w-40">
                                <div class="text-gray-800 font-medium" x-html="netTotal"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" justify-between mb-3">
                            <div class="text-gray-400 text-md  flex font-bold uppercase "><span
                                    class="ml-5 mt-2">Adjustment:</span> <span
                                    class="text-lg  ml-2 text-gray-600"><span class="text-xl" >&#2547;{{this.totalCost-this.discount}}</span></span> </div>
                            <div class=" w-40">
                                <div class="text-gray-800 font-medium" x-html="netTotal"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=" justify-between mb-3">
                            <div class="text-gray-400 text-md flex font-bold uppercase "><span
                                    class="ml-5 mt-2">Balance:</span> <span
                                    class="text-lg  ml-2 text-gray-600"><span class="text-xl" >&#2547;{{this.balance}}</span></span> </div>
                            <div class="w-40">
                                <div class="text-gray-800 font-medium" x-html="netTotal"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>            
    <!--form-->
    </div>
</div>
    <!--discount-->
```

I am sort of posting all of it since I can't really figure out what the issue is.

[image: error message]

[image: error]

Comment: **What particularly** stops working? Any console errors?

Comment: The whole app crashes and I sort of have to refresh before I can use it again. This only happens when I try and input the discount amount after choosing an option.

Comment: Any error messages in the UI? Crash is a very vague word - check the console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Okay, so I have added the error messages. Is there anything specific that I should be looking at?

Comment: Thank you - now please post the minimal reproducible example of the code in **text** as images are hard to copy & paste/debug/cannot be read by screen readers etc.

We need more code as it looks like you may have a processing lock somewhere in your JS code

Comment: I don't think the error message about `navigator.userAgent` and etc. is relevant to your issue at all. Without seeing your whole code, it's difficult to find out what went wrong. What have you tried in debugging the code? Add debug flags in selected checkpoints and see where your app stalls. Or do the 50/50 approach: remove half of the code, and test. If the code works, means you've found the problematic segment, if not, repeat.

Comment: On the other hand, why are you calling `applyDiscount()` in your template? This is probably why you're getting the error: the method is called whenever your template is re-rendered. If `applyDiscount()` contains code that causes re-rendering, then you basically run yourself into an infinite loop. That's probably why. Do you mean to execute the logic in `applyDiscount()` in a lifecycle hook instead?